# Confluent Control Center no clusters found

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, confluent-control-center

I am following this tutorial-
https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/platform-quickstart.html

At step 3 when I click on "Connect" I see no option to add connector.

[image: Screenshot of Control Center]

How do I add a connector?

For reference I am using M1 Mac book Air and Docker v4.12.0

Answer (score 1):

You'll only be able to add a connector if you are running Kafka Connect server, and have properly configured Control Center to use it.

> On Mac: Docker memory is allocated minimally at 6 GB (Mac). When using Docker Desktop for Mac, the default Docker memory allocation is 2 GB. **Change the default allocation to 6 GB in the Docker Desktop app by navigating to Preferences > Resources > Advanced**.

Assuming you already did that, then you need to look at the outputs from `docker-compose ps` and `docker-compose logs connect` to determine if the Connect containers are healthy and running.

Personally, I don't use Control Center since I prefer to manage connectors as config files, not copy/paste or click through UI fields. In other words, if Connect container is healthy, try using its HTTP endpoints directly with curl/postman, etc

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue with there being no way to add a Connector.

Updating the container version from my old version `6.2.1` to `7.3.0` solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Updating docker-compose.yml with below solved my issue:

```
 control-center:
    image: confluentinc/cp-enterprise-control-center:7.3.1
    hostname: control-center
    container_name: control-center
    depends_on:
        - broker
        - schema-registry
        - connect
        - ksqldb-server
    ports:
        - "9021:9021"
    environment:
        CONTROL_CENTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:29092'
        CONTROL_CENTER_CONNECT_CONNECT-DEFAULT_CLUSTER: 'http://connect:8083'
        CONTROL_CENTER_KSQL_KSQLDB1_URL: "http://ksqldb-server:8088"
        CONTROL_CENTER_KSQL_KSQLDB1_ADVERTISED_URL: "http://localhost:8088"
        CONTROL_CENTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: "http://schema-registry:8081"
        CONTROL_CENTER_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
        CONTROL_CENTER_INTERNAL_TOPICS_PARTITIONS: 1
        CONTROL_CENTER_MONITORING_INTERCEPTOR_TOPIC_PARTITIONS: 1
        CONTROL_CENTER_CONNECT_HEALTHCHECK_ENDPOINT: '/connectors'
        CONFLUENT_METRICS_TOPIC_REPLICATION: 1
        PORT: 9021
```

source: https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-all-in-one/issues/94#issuecomment-1236187420